# Running git via Process.Start in C# gives exit code 128

Tags: c#, git, process

I have this code to get a list of git branches:

```
// get a list of git branches
Console.WriteLine("Retrieving list of git branches...");
var branchLister = Process.Start("git", $"branch -vv > {Filename}");

// wait a moment
branchLister.WaitForExit();

// load up the list
var branches = File.ReadAllLines(Filename);
```

However when I run my program, a window briefly pops up and the exit code of the process (found in the debugger by examining `branchLister`'s properties) is 128, and the file is not created, thus the last line of code crashes.

If I run the command manually in a command prompt, it runs just fine:

`git branch -vv clean-git.txt`

However if I run it from the start menu the same behavior occurs as when I run it  in my program: a window pops up briefly and no file is created.

How can I get the output of the git command from my C# program? Or does git have an API I can use instead?

Comment: You could try using [GitSharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)

Comment: Another option to use Powershell in C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167387/run-git-commands-from-a-c-sharp-function/50968790 Disclaimer: one of the answers is mine

Comment: @ivMisticos GitSharp is dead since 2010. Surely prefer https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp

Comment: Any of libraries, it was the first one I found ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Process.Start` doesn't support redirection of standard output. I had to leave off the redirection and read from the process's `StandardOutput` property instead.