# HOW TO - Connect to DevOps Uninitialized Git Repository (git remote add origin to uninitialized repo)

Tags: c#, git, powershell, azure-devops, command

I am creating a Project with git on DevOps using API. By default DevOps creates a git repository with same same name as project. I already have a project on my local machine and want to connect to that git repo and push it there.

How can I do that? Please help.

P.S. : I have to do it programmatically with C# code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You have to add the proper `git remote`, found on the initial project repo page.

### Longer answer

After creating a new project, the repo page looks like this:
[image: new project in azdo]

The second block contains the code for getting adding existing repo from command line. Let's say I have this local folder at `C:\work\githubtest` and just follow the commands above.
For the example I'm showing above the red rectangle:

- what is in the folder; README-local.MD
- what I committed; the file above

[image: add local repo]

The suggested commands from the rectangle and the screenshot are:

```
git remote add origin https://yourorg@dev.azure.com/yourorg/GithubTest/_git/GithubTest
git push -u origin --all
```

### The result

[image: the result in AzDo]

### In C#

So, your question is how to do this [programmatically, in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50968790/8843952)?
Well the part of the git command is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167387/run-git-commands-from-a-c-sharp-function)
This could look in your example something like:

```
string directory = ""; // directory of the git repository

using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    // this changes from the user folder that PowerShell starts up with to your git repository
    powershell.AddScript($"cd {directory}");

    powershell.AddScript(@"git remote add origin https://yourorg@dev.azure.com/yourorg/GithubTest/_git/GithubTest");
    powershell.AddScript(@"git push -u origin --all");

    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: I was doing the same thing, only while doing "git remote add origin <remote repo url>" I was passing wrong url (GitRepository.Url instead of GitRepository.WebUrl). Thanks promicro for the quick reply.