# Need help running GitHub commands in C# Console

Tags: c#, console, updates, github-api

This is a re-upload of [Run git commands from a C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167387).

I am creating an update system for my C# Console Project and would like to use git commands to pull the latest version and update itself. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57376993/6527049) answer should help you to get a basic understanding.

So now you have to run two sets of commands.

Push:

```
add -A
commit -m "explanation_of_changes"
push origin branch_name
```

Pull:

```
pull origin branch_name
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean